# Dagger not generating Component classes

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have tried a great deal debugging this issue but unable to find the cause. Dagger simply doesn't create the DaggerComponent classes. I've checked SO for duplicates but none of the solutions provided worked.

**project's build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app's build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hr.crux"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

retrolambda {
    jvmArgs '-noverify'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

**HttpModule.java**

```
@Module
public class HttpModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit getRetrofit() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/")
                .build();
        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

**HttpComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {HttpModule.class})
public interface HttpComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

}
```

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

private static Application application;

private HttpComponent appComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    application = this;
    appComponent = //Cannot find DaggerHttpComponent
}


public static Application getInstance() {
    return application;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

Dagger is failing to generate the component class in my Application class. I've tried clean building, I've tried invalidating cache but nothing works.

Comment: is it *failing* with an error, or is it not generating anything and the build itself succeeds? If there is an error, provide the error.

Comment: Thanks, but Its not failing with any error. The build succeeds but the DaggerComponent class is never generated

Comment: Does it generat anything at all? There should be a whole bunch of factories and the sorts.

Comment: Nope man its not generating anything.The apt folder is empty which I suppose contains the dagger generated files

Comment: I just successfully clean built a project with your gradle configuration, so this seems not to be it. Do you know that you have `support:appcompat` included twice? I doubt that this would be the issue, though.

Comment: I've removed the same, it doesn't compile all the same. As suggested before I've clean built a lot to no avail

Comment: Thanks @David, Finally go it to work removed the duplicate imports and  clean built it and removed all other libraries.WIll debug this seems like some library was interfearing and post a proper solution

Comment: @humblerookie could you share that proper solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a fresh project by yourself instead of following the tutorial project. If you do so, here is the solution.

These two lines are responsible to generate the compile-time framework in Dagger 2.

`compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'`//generates framework in compile time
 `annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'` //generates framework in compile time based on the annotations you provided.

**Full setup Dagger**

```
        //dagger 2
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'

        //to enable DaggerActivity, DaggerBroadcastReceiver, DaggerFragment etc classes
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.14.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14.1'

        //support libraries with dagger 2
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.14.1'
```

**Note**: You need to configure Annotation Process as provided in the screenshot below. You can do this `File>Other Settings>Default Settings>`search`"Annotation processor"`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### As Other threads' Answers does NOT work for me:

I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832609/3084189)

`Pref -> Editor -> File Types -> Ignore Files And Folders -> Remove "Dagger*.java;"`