# Dagger 2 component not generated

Tags: android, dagger

In my module, in my base Application class

```
component = DaggerCompClassComponent.builder()
                .classModule(new ModuleClass()).build();
```

it can not find DaggerCompClassComponent.

I have on module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
.........................
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

and in Project build.gradle,

```
 classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

I have done build / rebuild / clean / restart project. I have a Component class where I inject objects and a ModuleClass where I provide objects to inject.

What can be the cause for not generating Dagger Component . class ?

EDIT:

This is my ModuleClass, adnotated with @Module:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public Interceptor provideInterceptor() {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

            builder.addHeader("AppName-Android", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME + "-" + BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return chain.proceed(builder.build());
        }
    };
}

@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Interceptor interceptor) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
    return builder.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient client) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseApplication.getRes().getString(R.string.api_base_url))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
WebServiceCall provideWebService(Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(WebServiceCall.class);
}
```

And this is my Component Class:

```
@Component(modules = ModuleClass.class)
@Singleton
public interface ComponentClass {

    void inject(Interceptor o);
    void inject(OkHttpClient o);
    void inject(Retrofit o);
    void inject(WebServiceCall o);

}
```

Comment: Add your Components and Modules to the question

Comment: Those `void inject(...)` methods are all wrong, remove all 4 of them

Comment: @EpicPandaForce , I have deleted - no effect!

Comment: In that case you should check the compiler's messages and see if there's anything else that failed.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ,  
Error:(25, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerClassComponent
Error:Execution failed for task ':sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Something before or after that. Or your import statement is missing.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce , I ve got this warining:

Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.

Comment: You probably mixed `annotationProcessor` and `apt` in your `build.gradle`. Replace all `apt` with `annotationProcessor` and remove `apply plugin: 'android-apt'`.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

When developing on Kotlin, you should add the following lines next to their `annotationProcessor` counterparts:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

and add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` at the start of the same file.

That section looks like this for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // <- Add this line
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Answer (score 45):

### Update (March 29, 2020)

Inside your **app-level** `build.gradle` inside `dependencies` block, add these lines:

```
     //dagger2
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'

     compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
     implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Inside `android` block of **app-level** `build.gradle`,

```
kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
```

At the **top** of the **app-level** `build.gradle`, Do this in **exactly below order**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Finally, You need to configure Annotation Process as provided in the screenshot below. You can do this `File>Other Settings>Settings for New Projects>`search`"Annotation processor"`
[image]

After this, do from Menu `Build > Rebuild`. You are done!

**Test:**

```
@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent {

}
```

Now, you can use `DaggerApplicationComponent` that was generated at compile-time for your ApplicationComponent interface.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ApplicationComponent applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.create();


}
```

Comment: The correct path to allow "annotation processor" on Windows is File -> Other Settings -> Settings for new projects...

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you forgot to annotate ModuleClass with @Module ?

Answer (score 5):

If you have several modules in your AndroidStudio (modules in terms of Android Studio, not Dagger), another possible reason of fail is that you've forgot to put annotation processors into the all modules' `build.gradle`.

We've divided our app into several modules, updated dependencies from using `implementation` to using `api` but forgot to handle annotation processors accordingly.

So, you can have this lines only in a root module:

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16'
// if you use the support libraries
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16'
```

But this ones should be specified in all modules dependencies:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
// if you use injections to Android classes
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'
```

Answer (score 3):

If Dagger2 can not generate its components it means that your code have some errors with Scopes/Modules. Check our your @Provides/Inject methods.

**UPD:**

You should inject your components into cases where you need instances of classes provided by module.

like

```
inject(MainActivity main);
```

Comment: @hackingforgirls void inject(Interceptor o);
    void inject(OkHttpClient o);
    void inject(Retrofit o);
    void inject(WebServiceCall o); what the point of it?

Comment: @hackingforgirls you should inject your components into classes where you want module instances injected

Comment: I have injected the dependences that I need in my project. Why should I delete them?

Comment: @hackingforgirls as I said void inject(Interceptor o); void inject(OkHttpClient o); void inject(Retrofit o); void inject(WebServiceCall o); is totally wrong and make no sense at all. Read some tutorials how to use Dagger 2

Comment: @AntonKazakov it is used to expose those objects to those who might need them as dependencies.

Comment: @Hohenhiem module class do it, but not the component

Comment: @AntonKazakov `@Provides` are used inside the module, but if you want to expose an object to another component, that is the time you declare the interface method that expose that object.

Answer (score 3):

In build.gradle's app, you need to add necessary dependencies for Dagger to generate corresponding classes, as below:

```
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.21'
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21' // if you use the support libraries
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
```

you should change dagger version which you are using.

refer full dagger document in [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone doing this in the year 2022 on Android Studio, if you want to just use *some* Dagger capabilities, you only need to add this in your Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.41'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.41'
```

then this on your plugins:

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
```

You don't need to add anything else.

Now here's the key step: **You need to do a clean (either in Gradle or just select Clean Project under Build menu) because for some reason incremental compilation is getting in the way.**

*Then* rebuild your project.

If you created your Dagger components correctly you should see compilation errors at this point, or if you created them correctly the auto-completion with your component(s) should now work in the code editor.

Comment: "Clean Project " This do work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are some minor misconceptions/faults in your code above, here's a working implementation:

**Application.java:**

```
component = DaggerComponentClass.builder().classModule(new ModuleClass()).build();
```

The generated class will be named `DaggerComponentClass`, not `DaggerCompClassComponent`. If you can't run your app in Android Studio to get it built, try Build->Clean project and Build->Rebuild project in the menu. If everything is OK Dagger will have compiled `DaggerComponentClass` which will be located in the same package as `ComponentClass`.

**ComponentClass.java:**

```
@Component(modules = ModuleClass.class)
public interface ComponentClass {
    void inject(AClassThatShouldGetInstancesInjected instance);
}
```

A Component in Dagger2 has methods named `inject` that receive the instance to get instances injected into it, not the other way around. In the code above the class `AClassThatShouldGetInstancesInjected` will typically call `componentClass.inject(this);` to get instances injected into itself.

**ModuleClass.java:**

```
@Module
public class ModuleClass {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Interceptor provideInterceptor() {/*code*/}

    //Your Providers...
}
```

The Module is correct in your code, make sure its annotated.

Comment: `I removed @Singleton from ComponentClass since it's an annotation that is only relevant for modules.` um, no?

Comment: EpicPandaForce Might be a wrong assumption, but from what I've seen in the documentation @Singleton isn't used in Components

Comment: now you've actually made me uncertain, but i think applying scope on the component makes it a "scoped component" which will make it see all `@Singleton` annotated classes with `@Inject` constructor, and it is in a lot of examples you can find lingering around here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40751767/2413303 but maybe we were all wrong, haha

Comment: I added strike-through over that part! I found a use of `@Singleton` in Components in the *new* official docs for Dagger2 https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html so guess you're right ;)

Comment: @PärNilsAmsen I don;t get what is the change you suggest. What I have to modify?

Comment: @Singleton is just Dagger2 scope, but its predefined. Scopes defines lifetime of components and their modules.

Comment: @hackingforgirls improved the answer somewhat to make it clearer. It's pretty much the basic implementation from the docs now, `AClassThatShouldGetInstancesInjected` is typically your Activity that wants to get injected by Dagger.

Comment: In my case, my ComponentClass was named DaggerMainComponent. I didn't notice that I misspelled the name when building it in my Application class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Kotlin, make sure to add `kapt` (Kotlin annotation processor) Gradle plugin to your build script and use `kapt` Gradle dependency type instead of `annotationProcessor` for Dagger Compiler.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt

kapt deps.daggercompiler
implementation deps.dagger
```

Answer (score 2):

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.28.3'
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.28.3'
```

Replace above with below dependencies in app level dependencies, if you have used above

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by editing my dagger dependencies to this:

```
 implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${versions.dagger}"
 kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${versions.dagger}"
```

Answer (score 1):

### As Accepted Answer does NOT work for me:

This issue is related to Android Studio (`V4.1.2` and up) and you can fix it by doing the below steps:

`Pref -> Editor -> File Types -> Ignore Files And Folders -> Remove "Dagger*.java;"` 
Also If you see other Dagger regexs, remove them too.

Now android studio will find generated component class.

Comment: on my android studio 2021.3.1 Patch 1 not exist for `"Dagger*.java;" `

Answer (score 1):

I spent one hour on this because I was mistakenly using the wrong imports.

```
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Module
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Provides
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Component
```

Correct imports:

```
import dagger.Component
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
```

Comment: Nice find friend! I was thinking the same thing when I just ran into this issue on some legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't being created only in Instrumentation Testing, because I was missing

```
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
```

Of course I'm using Kotlin and `$rootProject.daggerVersion` is a property on my base build file. You can replace for whatever version or gradle dependency you desire and are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked for me with Kotlin. Just this much in `build.gradle (Module YourProject.app)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {
    .....
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many modules in one project, you can choose to generate Dagger2 classes for one module by using below command.

`./gradlew <module-name>:kaptDebugKotlin`

Answer (score -2):

```
//add all the dependencies otherwise component class will not be generated.
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.21'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
```

Comment: Please fully explain your answer, and what it contributes to the other answers for this question.